# ¿ Cómo mover los botones de Data table?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

tengo problemas con la posición de los botones de datatable, y no tengo idea de como modificar las posiciones, lo que quiero es ponerlos en otro lugar de la tabla.

-Algo no  esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya que normalmente esta de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si kitas los botones de arriba la fiferencia de abajo se soluciona????

Comment: Asi es Estaria a la misma altura

Comment: Bueno pues lo ke tienes ke ver es como no renderizar los del datatable, crear los tuyos en html donde desees y asignarle en el onclick la función de los del datatable. YO YA LO HICE 1 vez y funciona

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu código HTML,CSS y JS? Ayudaría mucho a poder ver el problema

Comment: Bueno pues lo ke tienes ke ver es como no renderizar los del datatable, crear los tuyos en html donde desees y asignarle en el onclick la función de los del datatable. YO YA LO HICE 1 vez y funciona – Dariel Ramos Díaz de Villegas el 25 may. a las 18:30 ----- Me interesa como se hace????? saludos

Comment: @AbrahamQuezadaLizarraga si tienes una pregunta parecida, debes crear tu propia publicación, y si añades código seguramente recibas una respuesta rápida (poner botones en un datatable no es complejo, pero hace falta ver como se inicializa el datatable para poder dar una respuesta concreta y especifica a tu caso). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información, y crea tu propia publicación. Un saludo.

Comment: Como agregaste esos botones de excel y pdf arriba, cuando yo agrego se oculta el selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segun investigue ahorita tiene que ver con el "dom"

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

me pasaba lo mismo cuando tenia:
dom: 'Bfrtip'

No encontre una forma concreta de solucionarlo porque aveces el dom funciona bien y en otras pasa lo que te paso a ti, que asigna "i" y "p"  (informacion y paginacion) como elementos de bloque que ocupan todo su ancho disponible y por eso ves a informacion ocupando toda una linea y abajo a la derecha ves al elemento de paginacion, yo lo solucione con css agregandole clases a dichos elementos "los de informacion y paginacion" y en estas clases los convertia en elementos de tipo inline-block, te comparto mi solucion en codepen:

Datatables Bootstrap 4 con botones de exportar con estilo:

https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/gKqLEK

si tienes dudas sobre el código puedes preguntarme aunque creo que se puede entender fácil con verlo.