# Conflicto entre lBfrtip (botones) y buscador

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-4

Estoy teniendo este problema, no logro que los botones queden a la par del search ubicado a la derecha.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da igual si se muestran los botones arriba del numero desplegable o por debajo, pero quiero que quede alineado al search al menos uno.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente code:

```html
<script>
  $(function () {
    
    $('#example1').DataTable({
      "dom": 'lBfrtip',
      "buttons": ['excel', 'pdf', 'copy'],
      "paging": true,
      "scrollX": true,
      "lengthChange": true,
      "searching": true,
      "ordering": true,
      "info": true,
      "autoWidth": false

    });

  });


</script>
```

Tambien he probado con Blfrtip y ocultando el lengthChange a false, pero ocurre lo mismo, es como si hubiera un salto de linea.

Answer (score 0):

No hay ningun salto de linea, lo que sucede es que pasa a ser del tipo bloque, hace mucho que tuve problemas con eso, no recuerdo la razon exacta pero lo solucione editando el CSS a full xD

Aqui te dejo la respuesta que di a esto anteriormente:
[¿ Cómo mover los botones de Data table?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167821/c%C3%B3mo-mover-los-botones-de-data-table/177199#177199)

Oh si no quieres leer te dejo la solucion rapida

Datatables con botones de exportar y bootstrap 3 + personalizacion de estilo

https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/XYOPEP?editors=0110

Datatables con botones de exportar y bootstrap 4 + personalizacion de estilo
https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/gKqLEK

Si te gusta mi respuesta marcala como correcta :3 soy medio nuevo en esto del stackoverflow pero ayudo con lo que puedo de repente, igual si tienes alguna duda y te la puedo resolver puedes ponerla con gusto en un comentario :3